Allow us to flag reviews
Please allow us to flag reviews in the review queues. Possible use cases/Flag options for this could include:

Incorrect reviews/Suspected robo-reviewing
User persistently spamming queues with obviously bad suggestions/flags/votes (ex.vandalism)
Review audit is incorrect

Yes, I know (for some of these cases) we could flag a related post with "In Need of Moderator Intervention" (and if totally necessary a random one), but that is annoying workaround. It makes much more sense for the flag to be on what the problem actually is, rather than a related, semi-related, or totally unrelated post.

Being able to flag incorrect reviews and incorrect review audits would be great.   Personally, I review less than I once did because of both of those issues.  Who would look at those flags?  At least for the former, the concern would be that it could be the same people performing incorrect reviews.

@EndAntisemiticHate certainly incorrect review audits would go to the mods. And robo-reviewing also seems like it should be mod only. And a user spamming the queues realistically requires either nothing, mod message, suspension, or destruction, so I think that would be mod only as well. I don’t imagine this being a huge number of flags, honestly.

Unfortunately, most incorrect reviews I see these days seem to be by mods.  Also, I need to check, but I thought it was uncommon for mods to take action to fix incorrect review audits when community members report them.  I vaguely recall nothing constructive happening when I reported incorrect review audits years ago, so I stopped reporting them.

I think the other category you mentioned (a user spamming the queues) is a great fit to be handled by mods.

@EndAntisemiticHate if you feel that way then the solution is better mods…I honestly can’t review on any site with review audits so I’m not incredibly familiar with them
